# Whats the correct way to make WPF's

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm making my first WPF in C# and using MahApps, wondering what's the way to deal with content changing, for example when you click a button and see a new page? do you do this via a new window, panels or any other manner?

I know its a very beginner question but id really appreciate the help also if this is the wrong place to ask a forward to the right place would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to navigate on a new window/page, try to lessen Visual Hierarchy and use more fixed sizes for processing the layout more faster.

and here is and ex of opening a new windows and page:

> Opening a new Window

```
TheWindow win = new TheWindow ();
win.Show();
```

> Navigating to a new page

```
ThePage tp = new ThePage ();
TheCurrentWindow.Navigate(tp);
```

Comment: Amazing! sounds like exactly what I need to learn next I'll look into it, thank you.